# mapping API: Google earth, Worldwind or OpenStreet MAP

Tags: dictionary, gps, openstreetmap, google-earth, worldwind

I would like to include MAP in an application which will update the route I travel. 
I have studied various map sources and listed Google Earth, Worldwind and Openstreet map. 
Can someone help me in choosing the right one. 
I might need offline use also.

Comment: It may help to know some more about the environment in which your application will run, and what language it will be written in.

Comment: Would prefer to write in Java

Answer (score 1):

I may advice you to choose Google earth: it is quicker and has better texture quality, in my opinion. It is also quite used so you can find a lot of information and examples about how to do things, whereas Worlwind is not so used (448 vs 38 tags in stackoverflow).